# How to develop a safari plugin(input managers) use SIMBL?

Tags: cocoa, simbl

Now I want to develop a safari plugin use SIMBL , but I searched a lot of webpage not found some sourcecode or simple sample , someone can give me or point to a location ? Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you consider writing a WebKit Plugin?
As far as I understand, SIMBL plug-ins are still some kind of Input Manager and therefore not well supported on new Mac OS X versions, and not supported at all if Safari runs as 64-bit process.

A good starting point to write a WebKit plug-in:
[Creating Plug-ins with Cocoa and WebKit](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/WebKit_PluginProgTopic/Tasks/WebKitPlugins.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001249)

You can also peek into the [ClickToFlash source](http://github.com/rentzsch/clicktoflash).
ClickToFlash is implemented as WebKit plug-in.

Comment: SIMBL was re-written to perform its injection via some other back door in the Scripting Additions loader.

Comment: OK. But that doesn't sound too well supported either. But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: ok,I have make a webplugin followed the ClickToFlash , because I want to get the flash address in webpage when safari run.but Used the ClickToFlash's methods I found that the flash in web will be stopped showing because the MIMETYPE be set the 'application/x-shockwave-flash'. So I think this method doesn't suit to me. I know that the SIMBL plug-ins not well supported on the snow lerpard , but someone maybe fit this . so I want to learn how to develop a SIMBL plug-ins . and have other methods for develop a safari plugin expect for SIMBL plug-ins and ClickToFlash Methods?